# Problems with pg_trgm % operator in parameterized SQL queries

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

This is probably an incredibly dumb question.

Either psyco2pg or postgres doesn't like the similarity operator. This works:

```
sql = 'Select * from movie where title = %s'
data = ('Clockers',)
cur.execute(sql, data)
```

But when I change the operator to the pg_trgm module's '%', I get a 'tuple index out of range' error.

```
sql = 'Select * from movie where title % %s'
data = ('Clockers',)
cur.execute(sql, data)
```

Is there a workaround?

Comment: That did it. Wish I could approve your answer. Thanks!

Comment: This is an incredibly good question :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `title %% %s`

(copied and pasted from comment)